# How use UrlHelper in signalR HubClass

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a Chat class drived from Hub.
I want to know if thers a way to built URL by URLHelper like :   Url.Action("action","Controller").

as i can derived the class from 2 abstract classes (Hub, Controller) i dont know if thers other way to build complete URls and not Hard code.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in my Hub currently, I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this works.

Note: If you want a a fully qualified url, make sure you set the domain correctly (example.com).

```
protected virtual UrlHelper Url
{
    get
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequest("/", "http://example.com", "");
            var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
            httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
        }

        var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBase, routeData);

        return new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 Years later, have you found any better code? I did not try it yet, but I think also that there should be something cleaner,

Comment: Is there any similar workaround for .NET Core 2.1? The classes where you create a instance of like `RequestContext` or `HttpRequest` are abstract in .NET Core.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with this, and I am using T4MVC.

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.RequestContext);
var url = urlHelper.Action(MVC.Directors.EventSchedule.Index(EventId));
```

Comment: Although this does give me an instance of UrlHelper, calls to `Action` throw a null reference exception due to the server vars being absent.