# the name url does not exist in current context in Signal R hub class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

This is my method to return back url in form of string but this method is in Signal R hub class. Now, problem is with Url.Action. It is not recognizing this extension method inside Signal R hub class.

```
 private string _GenerateUrl(int? Id)
     {
         var avatarImage = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == Id);
         if (avatarImage != null)
         {
             return Url.Action("GetFileData", new { fileId = avatarImage.Id });
         }
         else
         {
             return Url.Action("GetFileData", new { fileId = 7 });
         }  
     }
```

The error message is : the name url does not exist in current context. how should it be resolved. any hint please. It was working fine in normal controller but now its showing error in signal r hub class.

Comment: Without the rest of your file, this is a guess.  The `Url.Action` helper is a part of the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.  I'm guessing that it is not included.  On top of that, depending on your solution structure, it may not return the correct URL.

Comment: @drneel System.web.mvc is already there

Answer (score -1):

You can't use Url.Action inside a signalR class. You need a UrlHelper.
Check this answer [How use UrlHelper in signalR HubClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566692/how-use-urlhelper-in-signalr-hubclass)

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.  In particular, don't rely on links to provide the substance of your answer, as the linked resource may become unavailable - the link is welcome, but please also include the salient points directly in your answer.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.